# Two Foreign keys in @ManyToMany

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, many-to-many

im doing a pet-project and i need to implement friend feature. So, for example i have `user` entity.
And i need to make `@ManyToMany`  relationship with two foreign keys. Example of SQl explicitly created table:

```
create table friend_request(
    id int primary key
    ,sender_id int
    ,receiver_id int

    ,foreign key (sender_id) references users (user_id)
    ,foreign key (receiver_id) references users (user_id)
);
```

And its successfuly created, but i have no idea how to "connect" this table to actual business logic.

I tried creating like this.

```
@Entity(name = "friend_request")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    private List<User> users;
    


}
```

And here is code in `User` class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private List<UserUser> user;
```

But i got this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: ua.socialnetwork.entity.User.user column: user_id
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:409) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.checkColumnDuplication(Collection.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.validate(Collection.java:391) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Also, i have found a way of creating multiple `@OneToOne` , so i tried this:

Here is `UserUser` class:

```
@Entity(name = "friend_request")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User sender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User receiver;
}
```

And code in `User` class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender")
private List<UserUser> senders;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
private List<UserUser> receivers;
```

But again, i got the same error as before.
C`aused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'user_id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'ua.socialnetwork.entity.UserUser' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)`

It says to use

```
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

but i tried all of theese and next tricks from logs, and its all not working.

So, overall, how to can i create a table with 2 foreign keys from the same entity with an ability to persists data later?

Comment: Something like this: `@ManyToMany@JoinTable(name = "friend_request", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "sender_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "receiver_id") }) List<User> sender;` should work, though I have not actually tested it

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that friend requests are not only a connection between users but also carry data like whether it was accepted or not, so I'd use the second approach of representing the friend request as an entity of its own (I'd rename `UserUser` to `FriendRequest` in that case). Then sender and receiver would be named differently, e.g. something like this (I can't test it right now so it's only off the top of my head - use with caution):

```
@Entity(name = "friend_request")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FriendRequest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    //add additional data as needed

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
    private User sender;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
    private User receiver;
}

@Entity(name = "user") 
//other annotations
public class User {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sender")
   private List<FriendRequest> sentRequest;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
   private List<FriendRequest> receivedRequests;
}
```

You got it almost right but there's one error in your approach: the join column name is the name of the column that contains the foreign key not the one that's referenced, i.e. `sender_id` and `receiver_id` but not `user_id`.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. I`m kind of new in Hibernate, the @JoinColumn and @JoinTable
annotation creates separate tables, or columns and parameter (name = "") specifes the name of it?  How only the problem how to persist that data, because i cant just create via JpaRepo, but it is another story) Thanks!

Comment: @cumbainer well, I'd define the friend request as a separate entity with its own repository. You'd probably want to check for old requests, those that have been accepted or haven't etc. - all operations that would make sense in a separate repo :)

Answer (score 0):

The `@JoinTable` annotation uses the same column for both join directions.

```java
@JoinTable(name = "user_user",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
)
private List<User> users;
```

Inverse join should be: `inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")`

Comment: Yeah , thanks. Logs dont show it. So i was kind of hard to scrutinise without a ton of investigation time)